# Need declare protocol in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder if it is needed to declare the protocol.

So, I delete a part that protocol declare code.

I thought that it will happen compile error.

but, Has been running without any problems.

Why need protocol declare part?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SingleComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController {
// <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {   ==> protocol declare part
    IBOutlet    UIPickerView *singlePicker;
                NSArray *pickerData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerData;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end


<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> <= this is what feature?
                                                  When omit this, excute without any problem.
```

Below is picture After compiled screen.

It has no issues.

And excute without any problems..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring the Protocol here, you are merely specifying that the your class `SingleComponentPickerViewController` follows the protocols you specify.

The protocol needs to be specified if you are using any components and are setting you `SingleComponentPickerViewController` as their delegate. This is so the compiler knows that your class follows that specific protocol and you have implemented any required protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

It doesn't **declare** a protocol, it tells the compiler that your class **conforms** to the listed protocols.

It's needed, so other classes can know your class conforms to their protocol(s). If you omit them, you won't get a compiler error, but the delegate methods you declared in your class may not be called.

Comment: the delegate methods *will* be called, but you will get a warning from the compiler when setting the delegate as the compiler has no way to check that the said object conforms to the required protocol.